# How i attach swf file with flexPaper

Tags: flexpaper

i want to simply display .swf files in brpwser for that i have downloaded FlexPaper but i am confused that how i attach swf file with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the snippet I have used :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   highlightPageMenuLink();
  var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";  // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
    var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf"; // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string.  
    var flashvars = { 
      SwfFile : escape("<%= current_user.book.name%>.swf"),
        Scale : 0.6, 
        ZoomTransition : "easeOut",
        ZoomTime : 0.5,
      ZoomInterval : 0.1,
      FitPageOnLoad : false,
      FitWidthOnLoad : true,
      PrintEnabled : false,
      FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
      ProgressiveLoading : true,
      PrintToolsVisible : false,
      ViewModeToolsVisible : true,
      ZoomToolsVisible : true,
      FullScreenVisible : true,
      NavToolsVisible : true,
      CursorToolsVisible : true,
      SearchToolsVisible : false,
      localeChain: "en_US"
    };

    var params = {}
    params.quality = "high";
    params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "FlexPaperViewer";
    attributes.name = "FlexPaperViewer";
    swfobject.embedSWF("FlexPaperViewer.swf", "flashContent", "650", "605", swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);
    swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
</script>
```